# MySQL Update syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to have MySQL query like this one:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET
    1 = 1
WHERE
    ID = 257
```

But I got the syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 = 1 
WHERE ID = 257' at line 3
```

Need to perform an UPDATE query without updating anything.
What are the solutions?

Comment: what is purpose of running query without updating anything? Mysql will not allow u to do this

Comment: @Andrey: -1. While I've never had the need to just run a no-op query by itself, it's quite common to do this with `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE...` queries.

Comment: Presumably, he wants a trigger to be triggered, or perhaps auditing to occur.

Comment: ok, but what is purpose of this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `ID` = `ID`
WHERE `ID` = 257
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET
    ID = 257
WHERE
    ID = 257
```

Would that work for you?